# Eliminating duplicate python versions installed on computer- Mac OS

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

I'm currently dealing with an issue that was probably caused when I first started programming and is now catching up with me. Before I knew much about programming, virtualenvs, pip, etc... I must have installed python in multiple locations on my computer from different sources. My Mac actually came with python installed (I didn't know beforehand). 
Typing a which command gives me these locations

```
$ which -a python
/opt/local/bin/python
/opt/local/bin/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Additionally

```
$type python
python is hashed (/opt/local/bin/python)
```

To emphasize the confusion that this is giving me, typing the "python" command in terminal
opens up Python 2.7.5.
This is fine, since I prefer using this version as my default.
Installing something with pip however, (for example virtualenv) is placed  in this location

```
virtualenv in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6
/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11.6-py2.6.egg
```

Currently I'm trying to figure out a solution to this problem, deciding on whether to reformat my macbook, or manually and meticulously try to fix the problem. Anyone have any advice?

Comment: remove all but `/usr/bin/python` then reinstall pip with `python get-pip.py` https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with `which -a ruby` and `brew unlink ruby && brew link ruby` didn't fix it. Even weirder is the version of ruby changed depending on whether I run `ruby --version` or `/usr/local/bin/ruby --version`.

I noticed my $PATH had duplicate /usr/local/bin references. I removed the one coming from `/etc/paths` and this reduced the duplicates, and `ruby --version` returns the expected version. I then changed it back and instead changed the (what I now realise is) superfluous /usr/local/bin in my `.bash_profile`. Again the correct version. I returned the whole thing to what it was before - again the correct version.

So in summary, try removing/re-adding any reference to the duplicate path and maybe OSX will right itself!